# How to prevent error handlers from firing multiple times on an Observable stream?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have a http service that handles http requests. It has a handler that treats errors by popping up a modal on the screen.

I also have an interceptor that catches requests to insert an authorization token in case they need one. The token is taken from requesting another service.

The problem is, if the authorization request is needed and it fails, the modal error is shown twice even if the second request is never sent.

If think there's something wrong in the way I'm dealing with the Observable stream. Could someone help please?

```
/// http service
  request(url, body, headers) {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, body, headers).pipe(
      catchError(() => this.handleError())
    );
  }

  handleError() {
    this.showModal();
    return throwError('Theres been an error.');
  }
```

```
/// interceptor
  intercept(request, next) {
    const authorization = request.headers.get('Authorization');
    if (authorization) {
      return this.httpService.request(url, body, headers).pipe(
        exhaustMap(token => {
          const newRequest = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set(
              'Authorization',
              token
            )
          });
          return next.handle(newRequest);
        })
      );
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `console.log` out the errors you're getting. It is possible that you're getting two differents errors.

Are you sure about this part of the code as well:

```js
const newRequest = request.clone({
  headers: request.headers.set(
    'Authorization',
    token
  )
});
```

In some libraries setting headers after a request is sent is not permitted.

Comment: I've already checked. One of the errors is from the authorization request. The other is from the original request.
Regarding headers, Angular Interceptors allow header change. Anyway, I'm not sending the same request, it's a new one.